# How to import multiple dat files and manipulate data for each file?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using Python 3 to import a large number of .dat files and manipulate the data within each file. I'm running into trouble manipulating the files iteratively using a for loop... I keep getting the response: 'not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)' My code is below. Any help is appreciated!

```
import glob
import numpy as np

file_list = sorted(glob.glob('*.dat'))
for f in file_list: 
        xvalues, yvalues = np.loadtxt(fname = f, unpack = True, usecols =(0,1))
```

Comment: Instead just try `data = np.loadtxt(...)` followed by `print(data)`. Numpy arrays are row-oriented so when you do `xvalues, y values = ...` you're trying to unpack the first two *rows* not columns. There are many ways to skin this cat but one of the simplest is to just transpose the array with `data.T`

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see you were using `unpack=True`. In that case it should work. But you might have a file that does not have two columns or is otherwise malformatted somehow. Best is to put a print statement or a breakpoint to see what file it's crashing on and investigate what the array returned for that file looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! You were right that one of the files was faulty, not the code!